# how to pass parameters to sql query

Tags: c#

Im using Sql compact server.I created table with varchar datas.But i select a particular column member to be an identity.im programming in c#.
I want pass the query. how can i achieve this? Im new to this sql compact,

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Please can u elaborate more on u r question..wat u want to do...

Comment: I want create a connection in that want to pass the query of creating table with selected column as identity.any column can change as identity

Comment: This question really isn't clear at all. As suggested, a sample of code showing what you are trying to do may help.

Answer (score 0):

sql compact has no differences to severbased sql in such basic things. create a insert query, a connection und execute the query on the connection.

see [SQL Server Compact 3.5 How-to Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb895908.aspx)